# Activity is resetting values

Tags: android, android-activity, background, task

I have an activity that sum distance according user walks. The problem is when app goes to background and after something around 50 minutes I resume activity, values start again. 
I have tried too many things to solve this problem without success.

Does someone have any idea?

Thanks

Comment: If you rotate the device, does it reset?

Comment: In fact, I don't allow screen rotation.

Comment: Its because of activity life cycle. Your activity restarts. Check my answer below it will do your job.

Comment: How do you get the distance information? And how does it work when the app is in the background?

Comment: Still working... If pass a short time period, you can bring app to front again and activity is updating correctly. Sometimes, seems that activity is killed by Android and restarted again

Answer (score 1):

You will need to implement the following two methods in your activity:

```
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
```

In `onSaveInstanceState()` you persist any relevant data, and in `onRestoreInstanceState()` you retrieve those persistent values and refresh the data for UI.

**Update**

After implements this methods, you need to add in your onCreate method

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(YOUR_KEY_DATA)) {
            long your_long = savedInstanceState.getLong(YOUR_KEY_DATA, 0);
      ......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use sharedPreference to save progress or similar value

```
//initialize

SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE); 
    Editor editor = pref.edit();    



  //To save values
    editor.putBoolean("key_name1", true);           // Saving boolean - true/false
        editor.putInt("key_name2", "int value");        // Saving integer
        editor.putFloat("key_name3", "float value");    // Saving float
        editor.putLong("key_name4", "long value");      // Saving long
        editor.putString("key_name5", "string value");  // Saving string
        editor.commit(); // commit changes

//and to get values
 pref.getBoolean("key_name1", null);         // getting boolean
    pref.getInt("key_name2", null);             // getting Integer
    pref.getFloat("key_name3", null);           // getting Float
    pref.getLong("key_name4", null);            // getting Long
    pref.getString("key_name5", null);          // getting String
```

example is taken from [here](https://androidexample.com/Android_SharedPreferences_Basics/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=126).

Answer (score 0):

```
//add below line in manifest where initialize activity

         <activity
            android:name=".activity.MainActivity"  
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution go to your manifest file and for that specific activity add below provided line:

```
<activity
        android:name=".yourActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        />
```

Comment: If the app is killed by the system (you're running out of memory for example), the app is killed. So doesn't matter if it's a single task or not, the Activity will be recreated. So it doesn't solve OP issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is [Run Background service](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/send-request.html) because even in background, app need to be fed